# Reduce memory used when reading LAS/LAZ using lidR

Tags: lidr

I want to save multiple height normalized .laz files as variables to my global environment in R, but the `readLAS()` function starts decompressing the .laz files, and there comes a point where my laptop can no longer allocate more RAM to R for storing variables. I tried using reducing the size of a laz file variable by  using the select function `select = "xyz0"` according to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338938/why-are-las-file-sizes-inflated-when-read-using-package-lidr-via-rstudio), which has reduced the size to 428 MB which was initially increased to 1.6 GB (without the select function) from 78.4 MB (original .laz file size).

Can I use the filter function to exclude anything else from the .laz file in order to further reduce the variable size, when the purpose is to create convex hull polygons? Basically, I want to reduce memory allocation size due to the way R stores LAS/LAZ files as variables.

Comment: It would be a nice feature if R uses the hard drive to temporarily store global environment variables especially with SSDs, which are so much faster than traditional HDDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found the best option to reduce the loaded memory. If you read carefully the vignette linked in the question you mentioned you also understood why reading a LAS files in R uses so much memory and you understood that there is nothing we can do. So, spoiler alert, you won't be able to load a lot of data at once. So what are the options?

**Use `select` in `readLAS` to drop unused attributes**: you already found that one but for completeness of the answer I'm saying it again. This is the simplest way to reduce the amount of memory loaded

**Use `filter` in `readLAS` to drop unused points**: for example you may want to work only with first returns `readLAS("file.las", filter = "-keep_first")`.

**Use the `LAScatalog` engine**: to apply your routine one LAS file at a time and automatically save the outputs in files. If loading one file is still too much the engine has the capability to work with smaller chunks (e.g. 500 x 500 m). `LAScatalog` engine is **the** answer to your question but is an advanced tool. We wrote a lot of resources about this feature

- [A vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAScatalog-engine.html) that documents the engine
- [A book chapter](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html) that introduce the LAScatalog with more examples and images. It is more a tutorial than a manual
- [Another vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAScatalog-engine.html) that shows how to apply a user-defined routine
- [Another book chapter](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/engine2.html) that introduce how to apply user-defined function with more examples and images. It is more a tutorial than a manual

My advice is to read the book first because it is more like a simplified and illustrated tutorial while vignettes are more like a comprehensive documentation and are less user-friendly.